# Make Column have Same Value as Similar Column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I'm using phpMyAdmin and I was wondering if there is a way I can default a column to have the same value as another column?

**Scenario**

So I'm running a wordpress and I want to give users access to a page for a certain amount of time so I created a trialTime column. I want to default the value of trailTime to the users registrationDate (which is also a column). This way I can start the countdown from when they register but the admin will be able to reset the value of trialTime inside the admin panel if they want to.

Comment: I think you cann't do it by default, but after adding column you can do it with simple query for all users. "UPDATE table SET column1 = column2"

Comment: Whelp if I can't do it by default I guess time to go on with plan B which is what you said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using wordpress and want to set certain user field at time of registration, just use *user_register* action hook.

```
function set_that_additional_thing ($user_id) {
     global $wpdb;
     $wpdb->query("UPDATE `" . $wpdb->prefix . "users` 
                   SET `copy_field` = `field` 
                   WHERE `user_id` = " . $user_id);
}

add_action('user_register', 'set_that_additional_thing ');
```

Comment: This seems like a great solution to my problem but I don't understand where it's pulling the user id (to pass as an argument). If this hooks into the user registration then user id wouldn't be set yet would it?

Comment: This particular hook is called just after user is added to the database. So user_id is already known. As you can see, you are updating (UPDATE in mysql query) an already existing database entry.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Wordpress whiz, but I wonder if you could manually code this using the `WPDB` class.  It allows total control over the database.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you might be overthinking the problem. Why not just insert the same value into both columns at the time the registration is created.

Comment: Well I'm not sure where the registration is happening but i'm assuming it is somewhere in the core which usually isn't a good idea to edit since it gets overwritten with each update.

Answer (score 0):

A [default column value](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/data-type-defaults.html) in MySQL must be a constant, with the exception that you can use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` for a `TIMESTAMP` column.

If the record is created at the time of registration, then using a `TIMESTAMP` column with `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` may suffice.

Alternatively, you could handle this when reading the value from the database, something like this:

```
SELECT IFNULL(trialTime, registrationDate) AS trialTime
```

I'm assuming that the values could differ, otherwise you wouldn't need the trialTime column at all.